# automatic decay of lambda to function pointer when passing to template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda, function-pointers

Is there a way to make a lambda decay to a pointer, without explicitly casting to the right signature? This would tidy some code:

```
template<typename T> T call(T(*func)()){ return func(); }
int ptr(){ return 0; }
int main(){
    auto ret1 = call(ptr);
    auto ret2 = call((int(*)())([]{ return 0; }));
    auto ret3 = call([]{ return 0; });  //won't compile
}
```

It's evident that a call to `call` works only if the lambda decays to a pointer, but I'm guessing that that can happen only after the right function overload/template is chosen. Unfortunately I can only think of solutions that involve templates to make a lambda *with any signature* decay, so I'm back to square one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can change your lambda to use the unary `+` operator: `+[]{ return 0; }`

This works because unary plus can be applied to pointers, and will trigger the implicit conversion to function pointer.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone This has received much attention as [A positive lambda: `+[]{}` - What sorcery is this?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18889028/420683)

Comment: @Nikos not really. The unary plus there triggers the implicit conversion to a function pointer, because unary plus can be applied to function pointers. [See this](http://ideone.com/qnNOaR) as an example of what actually causes it to work.

Comment: @Nikos a function pointer is still a pointer. You have object pointer types, function pointer types and pointer-to-member types. I don't think the answer needs clarifying, but edit it if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you unnecessarily constrain yourself to function pointers without defaulted arguments and lambdas without captures, completely ruling out the huge family of functors (e.g. `std::function`, any results of `std::bind` and everything else that has a suitable `operator()`)?

Better just broaden your function signature:

```
template <typename F> 
auto call(F func) -> decltype(func()) { 
  return func(); 
}

int ptr() { return 0; }

int g(int i = 0) {return i;}

int main() {
    auto ret1 = call(ptr);
    auto ret2 = call((int(*)())([]{ return 0; })); //tedious, but works
    auto ret3 = call([]{ return 0; });  //ok now.

    auto ret4 = call(g); //ok now!
    int i = 42;
    auto ret5 = call([=]{return i;}); //works, too!
    auto ret6 = call(std::bind(g, i)); //and so on...
}
```

Comment: No, it happens every day that you have constraints due to other libraries that you are using.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone sorry, it wasn't clear to me from your question that `call` was part of a thirdparty API and cannot be changed. With that, the *positive lambda* shown by Simple is the weapon of choice.

Comment: Still an entirely reasonable solution. Inside `call`, you **can** convert to the function pointer type `decltype(func())(*)()`

Comment: @MSalters no, he can't. Firstly, because `call` is the thirdparty API function he can not change. Secondly, because the conversion is not allowed for general functors, functions with default arguments and lambdas with captures.

Answer (score 0):

As a TL;DR; implementation of the @Simple proposal, I have write a simple test as follow:

```
SCENARIO("decay_equiv", "")
{
    auto callback = +[](struct mosquitto *, void *,
                        const struct mosquitto_message *)->void{};

    typedef typename std::is_same<
            typename std::decay<decltype(callback)>::type,
            typename std::decay<void (*)(struct mosquitto *, void *, const struct mosquitto_message *)>::type
                    >::type s;
    std::cout << s::value << std::endl;
}
```

Try it removing the `+` in the callback definition and everything stop to work.