# Why can't I pass lambda in constructor with user-defined deduction guide?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a proxy class for a function which takes `Message` as parameter.

```
template<typename MsgType>
using SendFunctor = void(*)(MsgType&);

struct Message {};

template<typename T>
struct Test {
    Test(T t) {
        Message msg;
        t(msg);
    }
};

template<typename MsgType>
Test(SendFunctor<MsgType>) -> Test<SendFunctor<MsgType>>;
```

Inside `main` then I simply declare a variable and everything works fine both with free functions and lambda

```
Test test([](Message&) { std::cout << "Hello2" << std::endl; });
```

However, after adding another template parameter to `Test` and modifying the deduction guide

```
template<typename MsgType, typename T>
struct Test {
    Test(T t) {
        Message msg;
        t(msg);
    }
};

template<typename MsgType>
Test(SendFunctor<MsgType>) -> Test<Message, SendFunctor<MsgType>>;

// or what I really want to achieve
// template<typename MsgType>
// Test(SendFunctor<MsgType>) -> Test<MsgType, SendFunctor<MsgType>>;
```

I got an error `class template argument deduction failed`. In fact, everything works fine if I pass a free function to the constructor.

Can someone please explain to me, why lambda here breaks the entire deduction? And how can I fix this?

Comment: Your deduction guide doesn't really make sense in the second part. You're forcing `MsgType` to be `Message` anyway. What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

it doesn't *work* in the first case either, you're using the default deduction guide.

---

when you're writing

```
Test test([](Message&) { std::cout << "Hello2" << std::endl; });
```

it's actually deduced to

```
Test<some_lambda_type> test([](Message&) { std::cout << "Hello2" << std::endl; });
```

---

You can write

```cpp
Test test(+[](Message&){}); // + : convert it to function pointer
```

and both case should works.

Comment: i tested it and it looks not working, neither using the +

Comment: retested it better and seems to work, so sorry for bothering you

Comment: Alternatively: `SendFunctor<Message> t = [](Message&) { std::cout << "Hello2" << std::endl; }; Test test(t);`

Answer (score -1):

Lambdas without captures can implicitly be converted to function pointers, so other answers are wrong in that regard.

The problem is that the compiler cannot infer a template parameter from the lambda's argument's type. Think of it that way, if you passed a generic lambda (taking `auto` as an argument), what should be deduced?

Your example works fine, the only problem is the template deduction. You can `static_cast` your lambda manually to `SendFunctor<Message>` and it works as expected (https://godbolt.org/z/K5eveEM3c).

Comment: if an explicit cast is required, why are you saying they are implicitly convertible?

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper The explicit cast is required because the default template deduction guide is a better match without it.

Comment: @IkarusDeveloper one can convert (limited) lambda to function pointer, and deduce parameter type `T` from (that specific) function pointer, but cannot directly deduce `T` from a lambda

Answer (score -2):

lambda expression are objects (the type of that object is temporary defined by the compiler and any lambda has a different type) for which the compiler defines an operator(). <s>In short there's no implicit conversion from lambda type to function pointer</s>. In these cases I prefer to use `std::function` which has an adequate constructor to handle lambda expressions.

So a possible solution would be replace raw function pointer with `std::function` and encapsulate the *lambda expression* in a `std::function` to be passed to the constructor.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename MsgType>
using SendFunctor = std::function<void(MsgType&)>;

template<typename MsgType>
struct Test {
    Test(SendFunctor<MsgType> t) {
        MsgType msg;
        t(msg);
    }
};

struct Message {};

template<typename MsgType>
Test(SendFunctor<MsgType>) -> Test<Message>;

int main()
{
    SendFunctor<Message> f = [](Message&) { std::cout << "Hello2" << std::endl; };
    Test test(f);
}
```

here's a [live test](https://godbolt.org/z/6hc6xh3GM)

---- EDIT

Playing around a bit, I also solved the ambiguity in your deduction guide by using a struct helper to deduce the argument that takes a lambda expression, thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64782121/deduce-lambda-return-and-arguments-passed-to-constructor) which you can read for completeness.

here's the helper struct deducing the argument type of a lambda.

```
template<class C>
struct Get_LambdaFirstArg;

template<class C, class R, class Arg>
struct Get_LambdaFirstArg<R(C::*)(Arg&)const>{
    using type = Arg;
};
template<class C, class R, class Arg>
struct Get_LambdaFirstArg<R(C::*)(Arg&)>{
    using type = Arg;
};
```

Here's the new deduction guide defined to handle lambda expressions.

```
template<typename LambdaType>
Test(LambdaType) -> Test<typename Get_LambdaFirstArg<decltype(&LambdaType::operator())>::type>;
```

and here's a minimal example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename MsgType>
using SendFunctor = std::function<void(MsgType&)>;

template<typename MsgType>
struct Test {
    Test(SendFunctor<MsgType> t) {
        MsgType msg;
        t(msg);
    }
};

template<class C>
struct Get_LambdaFirstArg;

template<class C, class R, class Arg>
struct Get_LambdaFirstArg<R(C::*)(Arg&)const>{
    using type = Arg;
};
template<class C, class R, class Arg>
struct Get_LambdaFirstArg<R(C::*)(Arg&)>{
    using type = Arg;
};



struct Message {};

template<typename MsgType>
Test(SendFunctor<MsgType>) -> Test<Message>;

template<typename LambdaType>
Test(LambdaType) -> Test<typename Get_LambdaFirstArg<decltype(&LambdaType::operator())>::type>;

int main()
{
    Test test([](Message&) { std::cout << "Hello2" << std::endl; });
}
```

and here's a [live test](https://godbolt.org/z/vrv6q5cnb) of that example.

-- EDIT
finally i better tested the answer of @apple apple and it seems I was doing something wrong.
Using the + to convert lambda to function pointer and solves the ambiguity in your deduction guide.