# lambda function doesn't matches argument list

Tags: c++, list, pointers, templates, lambda

I am training using lambda function and I create a small function that merge two lists using template class. I want to use lambda function in order to compare age and merge them into a new list that will be in ascending order.
Compiler tell that `no instance of function template "merge_func" matches the argument list`.
If you can help me understand what is wrong in my lambda function, and how can I correct it.

```
 template <class T>
list<T*> merge_func(list<T*> first_list, list<T*> second_list, bool(*func)(T x, T y))
{
    list<T> merge_list;
    auto it_first = first_list.begin();
    auto it_second = second_list.begin();
    while (it_first != first_list.end() && it_second != second_list.end())
    {
        if ((*func)(*it_first, *it_second))
        {
            merge_list.push_back((*it_first));
            it_first++;
        }
        else
        {
            merge_list.push_back((*it_second));
            it_second++;
        }
    }
    while (it_first != first_list.end())
    {
        merge_list.push_back((*it_first));
        it_first++;
    }
    while (it_second != second_list.end())
    {
        merge_list.push_back((*it_second));
        it_second++;
    }
    return merge_list;
}

class Student
{
public:
    string _name;
    double _age;
    Student(string name, double age) : _name(name), _age(age) {};
};
int main()
{
    list<Student*> std;
    std.push_back(new Student("Lior", 15.5));
    std.push_back(new Student("Yossi", 60));

    list<Student*> std2;
    std2.push_back(new Student("Arie", 23));
    std2.push_back(new Student("Eli", 80));

    list<Student*> std3;

    std3 = merge_func(std, std2, [](Student* x, Student* y)->bool {return x->_age < y->_age; });
```

Comment: Your list store *pointers* not objects. `list<T>` should be `list<T*>`.

Comment: Your lists have a template type of `Student*` but your lambda expects `Student` arguments. Those two don't match

Comment: Your *second* problem is that your callback takes its argument as *objects*, not as pointers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks I have correct what you say but still not compile. What do you mean by `callback`. See my code I edit it

Comment: The `func` [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)). I.e. your lambda. Your `merge_func` function is passing *pointers* when it calls `func`, not objects.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't success correct the code. Can you help me edit the code to correct the issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22299052/4885321 add +before lambda

Comment: `*it_first` and `*it_second` are *pointers*. The type of e.g. `*it_first` is `Student*`. Just like you changed the list to use `T*` you must change `func` to use `T*` as its arguments. And that also means you must do the same update to the lambda.

Comment: Please don't change your code after some valid comments or answers were given. This way you make those answers look wrong. This also makes your question unusable to others who may have similar problems and seek a solution for them. If you want to present a fixed code _append_ it to your question below the original one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues.

1. The element type of the `list` is `Student*`, lambda should take `Student*` too.
2. You're passing lambda to `merge_func` which expects a function pointer. Template argument deduction doesn't consider implicit conversion (from lambda to function pointer) and fails deducing template parameter `T` on the 3rd function parameter.

You can change `merge_func` to

```
template <class T>
list<T> merge_func(list<T> first_list, list<T> second_list, bool(*func)(T x, T y))
```

And convert lambda to function pointer when calling `merge_func`.

```
std3 = merge_func(std, std2, static_cast<bool(*)(Student* x, Student* y)>([](Student* x, Student* y)->bool {return x->_age < y->_age; }));
```

Or perform the conversion with [sorcery `operator+`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18889028/3309790).

```
std3 = merge_func(std, std2, +[](Student* x, Student* y)->bool {return x->_age < y->_age; });
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/nNtK4tnV3zMJx2zz)

Or prevent deduction on the 3rd function parameter.

```
template <class T>
list<T> merge_func(list<T> first_list, list<T> second_list, std::type_identity_t<bool(*)(T x, T y)> func)
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZMGh5tlra0cWRccS)

Comment: Thanks ! If I understand all the problem is that I use `template` and the compiler doesn't know how to convert lambda to function pointer using template ? (Sorcery operator not work...)

Comment: @Ronyco123 Why `operator+` not work? It should be guaranteed. I tried it and works fine. https://wandbox.org/permlink/nNtK4tnV3zMJx2zz

Comment: I am on Visual Studio and operator+ not work. But the first solution works very well.

Comment: @Ronyco123 Got it. It might be just MSVC's bug.

Answer (score 1):

On top of @songyuanyao's answer, you can also utilize a more generic version.
Then the prototype of `merge_func` would look like this:

```
template <class T, class Compare>
list<T> merge_func(list<T> first_list, list<T> second_list, Compare&& comp)
```

and the if inside it:

```
if (invoke(std::forward<Compare>(comp),*it_first, *it_second))
```

Then it will be callable just with the lambda:

```
std3 = merge_func(std, std2, [](Student* x, Student* y) {return x->_age < y->_age; });
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/38f1vM3MW)

SFINAE/concept-related code is left for you to write ;)