# C++ Member-Function-Pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

I really need help for a excercise in C++ at the University. I have no idea how to solve it.
There is one Class with this memberfunction: `void Asteroid::render()` which is also `virtual` and I have to call this function from another class in the following way.

I have a template list which contains many asteroids, this is the class with the member function and the template has a function to pass over the function which should be called.
`void for_each(void (*do_something)(T item));` here I have to pass the pointer to `void Asteroid::render()` T in template are objects of the class Asteroid. So the final call in a third file looks like this `asteroids.for_each(HERE_THE_FUNCTION_POINTER);` `asteroids` is the declared `List<Asteroid>` and the function comes from the template.

So I really have no idea how to solve that and it's on the last minuites :( I hope you can help me so far. All the QNA's I have looked up didnt help just random compiler errors.

PS: I'm not allowed to change any declarations..

Thanks so far.

Method to Call:

```
void Asteroid::render()
{
// Compute transformation matrix
computeMatrix();

// Push matrix and set transformation and scaling
glPushMatrix();
glMultMatrixf(m_transformation);
glScalef(m_scale, m_scale, m_scale);
if(m_mesh)
{
    m_mesh->render();
}
glPopMatrix();
}
```

Method wich should call render():

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::for_each(void(*do_something)(T item))
{
Node* temp = this->m_list;

while (temp->next != NULL)
{
    if (this->m_list->next != NULL)
    {
        do_something(temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
}
```

Executing code part:

```
AsteroidField::AsteroidField(int quantity, string basePath) :
m_basePath(basePath)
{
// Generate asteroids
asteroids = List<Asteroid>();
Randomizer* random = Randomizer::instance();

for(int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
{
   TriangleMesh* mesh = TriangleMeshFactory::instance().getMesh(m_basePath + "asteroid.3ds");

   float size = random->getRandomNumber(1,5);
   Vertex<float> pos = random->getRandomVertex(5000);
   Asteroid asteroid = Asteroid::Asteroid(mesh, pos, size);
   asteroids.insert(asteroid);
}

}

AsteroidField::~AsteroidField()
{
asteroids.for_each(Asteroid::~Asteroid());
}


void AsteroidField::render()
{
// TODO: Call render for all asteroids
asteroids.for_each(*render());
}
```

Comment: If you post the code you have tried and the compiler errors, you might get some positive feedback.

Comment: @Criska, it's best to remove unnecessary parts and try to make an example, which can be easily recreated by others

Comment: @InnocentBystander I don't think `bind` can be converted to a function pointer. Lambdas on the other hand...

Comment: @Barry, by the time I was done fixing it, you already posted the answer. +1 from me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the signature:

```
template <typename T>
void List<T>::for_each(void(*do_something)(T item))
```

`do_something` here is a void function that takes a `T`. But your `render()` is not a free function, it's a class method. Its signature is `void (Asteroid::*)()`, which does not match. What we need is an intermediary step. Some function that takes an `Asteroid*` and calls `render()` on it:

```
void free_render(Asteroid* a) { a->render(); }
```

That function matches the required signature (with `T = Asteroid*`), and is something you can pass into `for_each`:

```
asteroids.for_each(free_render);
```

note that you will have to make sure you're using a `List<Asteroid*>` - which you should be doing anyway if `render` is a virtual method.

In C++11, we could use a lambda instead:

```
void AsteroidField::render()
{
    asteroids.for_each(+[](Asteroid* a){ a->render(); }
    //                ^^^^
    // see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889028/a-positive-lambda-what-sorcery-is-this
}
```

Comment: OK. Actually I get the error: expected expression
`asteroids.for_each(+[](Asteroid* a)){ a->render(); }`
The error is at this [ bracket

Comment: @Criska Are you using C++11? That's only valid for the new standard (my answer originally omitted the 11 part...).

Comment: Let me have a look to the CMakeFile EDIT: can't find anything about that and I haven't worked on with that.. I think I commit it with error and hope there are enough point ..
BUT THANKS FOR YOU HELP! I BELIEVE IT'S CORRECT