# C++ Lambdas and Variadic Templated Wrappers

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, function-pointers, variadic-templates

I am trying to execute the following code in C++. The program converts a lambda with no capture to a function pointer.

```
#include <utility>

template <typename R, typename... Args>
R run(R (*func)(Args...), Args&&... args) {
        func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int main() {
        run([] (int x, int y) {
            return x + y;
        }, 100, 200);
        return 0;
}
```

However, when I compile it, I get the following error -

```
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:11:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘run(main()::<lambda(int, int)>, int, int)’
         }, 100, 200);
                    ^
test.cc:11:20: note: candidate is:
test.cc:4:3: note: template<class R, class ... Args> R run(R (*)(Args ...), Args&& ...)
 R run(R (*func)(Args...), Args&&... args) {
   ^
test.cc:4:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cc:11:20: note:   mismatched types ‘R (*)(Args ...)’ and ‘main()::<lambda(int, int)>’
         }, 100, 200);
                    ^
```

As far as I am aware this is fine. I have also tried explicitly giving the template arguments in the call to `run`. That doesnt work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: `run(+[](int x, int y){ return x+y; }, 100, 200)` will work fine ;)

Comment: What does the `+` do?

Comment: Forces a conversion to a function pointer (the operand of unary + has a limited number of supported types).

Comment: It's one of the most silly ways to confuse readers of your source code. The actual issue in your code is that a lambda *is not a function* (nor a function pointer), and hence the pattern matching for function pointers (in the function parameter `func` of `run`) cannot be applied to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A lambda is **not** a function pointer. It cannot be deduced as a function pointer. It is a closure. However, if (and only if) it takes no capture, it can be explicitly converted to a function pointer via [some sorcery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18889028/2069064):

```
    run(+[] (int x, int y) {
    //  ^^^
        return x + y;
    }, 100, 200);
```

That said, it'd be better to simply have `run` take an arbitrary callable:

```
template <typename F, typename... Args>
auto run(F func, Args&&... args) 
    -> decltype(func(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) // only for C++11
{ 
    return func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```