# C++ Templated Delegates like Unity

Tags: c++, templates, delegates, variadic

after saw Unity's delegates and events, i'm trying to code my own:
I want to create a class with a variadic template, to specify the return type of the functions, and optionals arguments.

```
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
class MyDelegate{
    std::vector<Ret(*)(Args...)> vec;

    public:
    void operator+=( const Ret(*)(Args...)& newElement)
    {
        vec.push_back(newElement);
    }


    Ret operator()(const Args&... args)
    {
        for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); ++i)
            (*i)(args...);
    }
};
```

As you can see, i would like this class to be used this way:

```
MyDelegate<void> voidDelegate;
MyDelegate<void, int> intDelegate;
MyDelegate<int, char, boolt> miscDelegate;
```

and "adding" functions to each one using += operators, like:

```
voidDelegate += voidFunc;
//etc...
```

I'm having problem with the += operator for now, because VS don't accept this:

```
MyDelegate<void, int> delegate1;
delegate1 += [](const int a)->void{std::cout << a << std::endl; };
```

The lambda function is correct: it take an int and return void, so i don't understand whats' wrong.

Comment: In a closely related topic (delayed dispatching), you may find [**this question and top-answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7858971/1322972) particularly interesting. It hass come in handy for me numerous times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that your `std::vector` stores function pointers. It doesn't store `std::bind` objects, it doesn't store member functions, it doesn't store functors and it doesn't store lambdas. You are trying to add a lambda to it, hence the failure.

If you want to store any kind of object which supports calling with the correct argument and return types, you want `std::function`:

```
using FunType = std::function<Ret(Args...)>;
std::vector<FunType> vec;
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5921737a2739c32b)

Incidentally, you could improve your solution by perfect-forwarding your `operator()` args and copying your `newElement` arg in the interface and moving it into the `std::vector`.

Comment: If you have a std::vector of std::function, it can be difficult to remove an individual std::function at a later time.  Normally if you wanted to remove something from a vector, you'd find it first to get an iterator and then pass the iterator into vector::erase.  In the case of std::function, the find won't work because std::function's operator == is... strange (I can't remember the details).

Instead, you might want to use something like a vector of pair<function, unsigned> where the unsigned is some sort of serial number.  Then you can find using that serial number at a later time.

Comment: ... the only reason I'm so familiar with the problem is that I've spent a few days doing exactly this at my day job :)

Answer (score 1):

Your delegate accepts only function pointers. A lambda is not a function pointer. However, the lambda that you are trying to doesn't capture anything. Which means that it can be converted to a function pointer thanks to [some sorcery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18889028/2069064):

```
MyDelegate<void, int> delegate1;
delegate1 += +[](const int a)->void{std::cout << a << std::endl; };
             ↑↑↑
```

However, once you want to allow functors that have member variables, the extra `+` won't work:

```
delegate1 += +[x](const int a) { ... }; // error: no match for operator+
```

At which point you'll definitely have to use [TartanLlama](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31344114/2069064)'s suggestions of `std::function`.

Comment: @TartanLlama Super useful for using with C libraries that require function pointers or Boost.Python, which you'd think would allow functors, but doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

@TartanLlama's right, std::function is what you need.

And the calling loop can be folded to `for (auto handler : vec) handler(args...);`