# Template substitution fails when I change the type parameter name - compiler bug?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates, template-meta-programming, compiler-bug

Most of the following code has been taken from an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32045492/1928235) by Piotr Skotnicki. I was experimenting with it and discovered what I believe to be a bug in MSVC 14.0 Update 3.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct identity { using type = T; };

template <typename...>
using void_t = void;

template <typename F>
struct call_operator;

template <typename C, typename R, typename... A>
struct call_operator<R(C::*)(A...)> : identity<R(A...)> {};

template <typename C, typename R, typename... A>
struct call_operator<R(C::*)(A...) const> : identity<R(A...)> {};

template <typename F>
using call_operator_t = typename call_operator<F>::type;

template <typename, typename = void_t<>>
struct is_convertible_to_function
    : std::false_type {};

template <typename L>
struct is_convertible_to_function<L, void_t<decltype(&L::operator())>>
    : std::is_assignable<call_operator_t<decltype(&L::operator())>*&, L> {};

template <typename, typename = void_t<>>
struct is_callable_object
    : std::false_type {};

template <typename L>
struct is_callable_object<L, void_t<decltype(&L::operator())>>
    : std::true_type {};


int main()
{
    auto x = []() {};
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << is_callable_object<decltype(x)>::value;
    std::getchar();
}
```

This prints `true`, as expected, because the lambda object generated by the compiler does implement `operator()`.

Let's now change the type parameter name in `is_callable_object` from `L` to `T` (anything different from the type name used in `is_convertible_to_function` causes this problem, from what I see).

```
template <typename, typename = void_t<>>
struct is_callable_object
    : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_callable_object<T, void_t<decltype(&T::operator())>>
    : std::true_type {};
```

Suddenly, **this prints `false`**. `is_convertible_to_funtion` shouldn't matter since `is_callable_object` doesn't rely on it in any way; indeed, if I remove `is_convertible_to_function`, this problem disappears - I can use any type name I want.

As I said, I suspect this is a bug, so I'm asking this question to make sure that this isn't some bizarre behavior in the C++ standard; the workaround for this is quite easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression sfinae is non-functional in msvc 2015.  Any cases where it works are accidental, do not trust it.  `decltype` **cannot be used to cause sfinae in msvc 2015 reliably**.

Stop, walk away, and find another solution.  Maybe try compiler intrinsics.

Do not assume the accidental working when parameter names match means anything else will work, or it will work in a slightly different program.

Your workaround cannot be trusted.

Comment: I was wondering if your statement wasn't a bit too extreme, but even Microsoft themselves admit it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/02/partial-support-for-expression-sfinae-in-vs-2015-update-1/. Oh well, I'll keep experimenting, thank you.