# wrapping a C-function with a static callback parameter to a C++-function which accepts a private member as callback

Tags: c++, c++14, libsigc++

I want to wrap this C-function,

```
int sqlite3_exec(
  sqlite3*,                                  /* An open database */
  const char *sql,                           /* SQL to be evaluated */
  int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),  /* Callback function */
  void *,                                    /* 1st argument to callback */
  char **errmsg                              /* Error msg written here */
);
```

in a C++ function like,

```
namespace
IronMaiden
{
  int
  BookOfSouls::MyWrapper( DB* db
  , std::string& sql
  , ?? callback function ?? int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**) ?? )
  {
    .
    .
    .
    sqlite3_exec( db->get(), sql.c_str(), ?? callback ??, nullptr, nullptr);
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

I can pass any static function to `sqlite3_exec()`, but I want to pass a private member function from a `BookOfSouls` object as the callback function and I want to access the private data of the object from that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so after some tests and failures I got a way to achieve **EXACTLY** what I want to do.

My solution isn't straightforward... my fears come true...

After spending several hours to crawl on SO and internet ( *like in a dark, cold and creepy dungeon, with my light torch and some Angelscourge's music* ) I conclude there is **NO** such thing as a straightforward way!

```
         /*...I can't blame a C lib to don't support some C++ feature...*/
```

so, I needed to found another strategy... so I heavily used my brain (a.k.a. headbanging)... there popped a solution :

```
          /* The solution uses `libsigc++` AND a static function. */
```

The static function is in the namespace of the wrapper. This static function will do one thing, emit a signal. so if I take the same example as in the question,

```
namespace
IronMaiden
{
  sigc::signal<int,void*,int,char**,char**> signalCB; // `extern` is a friend
  .
  .
  .
  static int 
  callback( void *PersonalUse
          , int argc
          , char **argv
          , char **azColName )
  {
    return IronMaiden::signalCB.emit( PersonalUse, argc, argv, azColName);

  }
  .
  .
  .
  int
  BookOfSouls::MyWrapper( DB* db
                        , std::string& sql
                        , const sigc::slot<int,void*,int,char**,char**>& slotCB )
  {
    .
    .
    .
    sigc::connection signalConnection = IronMaiden::signalCB.connect( slotCB );
    sqlite3_exec( db->get(), sql.c_str(), callback, nullptr, nullptr);
    signalConnection.disconnect();
    .
    .
    .
  }
}
```

To connect a (**private member**) function, let say `YearOfTheGoat::ImTheCallbackFunction()`, from a `YearOfTheGoat` object,

```
YearOfTheGoat::ImSomeFunctionFromWhereIWantToUseMyWrapper()
{
  IronMaiden::MyWrapper( DBobj, transaction
                 , sigc::mem_fun(*this, &YearOfTheGoat::ImTheCallbackFunction) );
}
```

so now everytime that `sqlite3_exec()` calls `callback()`, that one will emit the signal, then calling `ImTheCallbackFunction()`

**some important notes :**

- in this example, the parameters and the return type of `ImTheCallbackFunction()` have to be identical to the ones of `callback()`.
- be aware to disconnect or the signal will stay connected.
- I got no issue with that solution so far. But you have to understand I wrote this answer right after I wrote the code in my program. So I'm not gonna claim it's **THE BEST** solution. But it **WORKS**!
- note about `sqlite3_exec`, it seems that the cb function is called only if there is something to returns.
- don't be confused between `BookOfSouls` and `YearOfTheGoat`. The first is **NON** instanciable. The second, I used an object. (N.B. since `BookOfSouls` is non instanciable, moving `callback` and `sigc::signal` inside `BookOfSouls` isn't a bad idea).

*comments are very welcome*

Answer (score 1):

The key is the `void*` argument:

```
int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),  /* Callback function */
void *,                                    /* 1st argument to callback */
```

The callback is a free function, but you can provide an arbitrary first argument into. So if you want to pass in a member function, we can take advantage of the fact that a no-capture lambda is convertible to a function pointer (thanks to [some sorcery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18889028/2069064)):

```
template <typename F, int (F::*mem)(int, char**, char**)>
void set_callback(F* f) {
        sqlite3_exec(db->get(), sql.c_str(), 
            +[](void* arg, int i, char** p, char**q){
                return (static_cast<F*>(arg)->*mem)(i, p, q);
            },
            f,
            nullptr, nullptr);
}
```

Note that the member function has to also be a template argument so that the lambda doesn't have to capture. It'd be simpler if you just required a particular function name, e.g. `sqlCallback()`, then your callback function would be:

```
+[](void* arg, int i, char** p, char** q) {
    return static_cast<F*>(arg)->sqlCallback(i, p, q);
}
```

Comment: well... I don't know what to say yet... except you are a sneaky coder... (I need to read carefully your answer)

Comment: I have the feeling that will not alow the use `this` in the callback. I have'nt tested yet. I want to crawl the sources of gtkmm to see how callback functions are wrapped from gtk (if I can figure that).

Comment: @bob-theunholymetalmachine You'd pass `this` as the argument, and then cast it back to its type as part of the callback to call the member function on. You can't access `this` within the lambda because it can't capture anything.

Comment: ok, but I want to point a function of an object and access is own private members. I can achieve the same that what you are proposing with a static method with this as an argument.