# Captureless lambda cannot be converted to function pointer when stored in std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, lambda, function-pointers

Usually, a C++ lambda without a capture [should be convertable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-lambda-as-function-pointer/28746827#28746827) to a c-style function pointer. Somehow, converting it using `std::function::target` does not work (i.e. returns a nullptr), also the `target_type` does not match the signature type even though it seems to be the same.

Tested on VC13 and GCC 5.3 / 5.2.0 / 4.8

**Minimal testing example:**

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void Maybe() {

}

void callMe(std::function<void()> callback) {
    typedef void (*ftype)();
    std::cout << (callback.target_type() == typeid(ftype)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << callback.target<ftype>() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    callMe([] () {});
    callMe(Maybe);
}
```

expected output would be

```
1
<address>
1
<address>
```

actual output

```
0
0
1
<address>
```

The question is: Why does the lambda's signature differ from the passed function?

Comment: _"... should be convertable to a ..."_ - citation needed.

Comment: @Useless Hmmm, [citation is here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28746827/1413395).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks, i included it in the question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your first call, `std::function` does not bother with decaying the lambda into a pointer, it just stores it, with its actual type (which is indeed not `void()`).

You can force the lambda to decay into a pointer *before* constructing the `std::function` with the latter by simply using a unary `+`:

```
callMe(+[](){});
//     ^
```

Comment: +1, But: I *really* dislike this `+` hack for integral/pointer type coercion. It just obscures the intent too much. Better make it explicit by wrapping this into a dedicated function.

Comment: So we found a dupe of [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889028/a-positive-lambda-what-sorcery-is-this/18889029?s=1|0.0000#18889029)?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ They are not strictly duplicates (the other ones are about type deduction and overload resolution), but they are indeed quite strongly related.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's a matter of getting used to it, I guess. Hiding it behind, say, a `decay(T&&)` function wouldn't bother me either.