# C++ member function overloading with & (ampersand)

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, ampersand

How to pick the correct **error()** member function? Do I need to cast somehow?

```
using namespace std;

struct test
{
   int error();
   void error(int x);
   int fun();
};

int main() {
   auto f1 = &test::error; // how to pick the correct function?
   auto f2 = &test::fun; // works
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Do I need to cast somehow?

Yes, you can use [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast#Notes).

> `static_cast` may also be used to disambiguate function overloads by
> performing a function-to-pointer conversion to specific type, as in
>
> ```
> std::for_each(files.begin(), files.end(),
>               static_cast<std::ostream&(*)(std::ostream&)>(std::flush));
> ```

So you can:

```
auto f1 = static_cast<int(test::*)()>(&test::error);
auto f2 = static_cast<void(test::*)(int)>(&test::error);
```

Comment: Dear lord, that's ugly.

Comment: Every time I see C++ type syntax I experience the urge to write something--anything--in Haskell.

Answer (score 35):

You can just explicitly specify the member function pointer type.

```
int (test::*f1)() = &test::error;
void (test::*f2)(int) = &test::error;
```

Comment: This; a cast is not specifically necessary, all that matters is that the compiler be able to disambiguate which overload should be used (and thus which type is desired).

Comment: I would add that adding a typedef would make things even more readables: `using error_func = int (test::*)(); error_func f1 = &test::error;`.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use a `static_cast` to disambiguate.

`&test::error` is not evaluable since the function is overloaded. The fact that you are assigning this to something marked `auto` is not immediately relevant.

One fix would be to use `static_cast<int(test::*)()>(&test::error)` or `static_cast<void(test::*)(int)>(&test::error)` as appropriate.

Then `auto` will work since there will be no ambiguity in the type deduction.

Answer (score 1):

Since an answer is already given, I'll present a solution that's easier on the eyes. This situation is perfect for a macro if you don't want to write out the cast every time:

```
template<class T>
using test_type_t = T test::*;
#define TEST_CAST(T, F) static_cast<test_type_t<T>>(&F)

auto f1 = TEST_CAST(void(int), test::error);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution when you don't have the internet to read up the ugly function-pointer-to-member syntax:

```
auto err1 = [](test& t) { return t.error(); };
auto err2 = [](test& t, int x) { return t.error(x); };
```

Note that up to now you get closures as types and not function pointers. If you wanted function pointers, which is useful if you want to store different member functions with the same signature in an array, you can cast the closure to a (normal) function pointer via `+` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889028/a-positive-lambda-what-sorcery-is-this)).

As far I can see at the moment, with the above you can do conceptually anything you can do with function-to-member-pointers -- except of course calling a routine which exactly requires such a pointer. And it's much nicer.