# c++ 11 - passing member function to thread gives: no overloaded function takes 2 arguments

Tags: c++, multithreading, function, member

From what I have looked up, my syntax is correct but my compiler (VS2015) is complaining. Note, I'm using namespace ee with the class Network. Here's the code

```
    //code that doens't work
    thread clientThread(&ee::Network::clientRun, new ee::Network);
```

*note: in the real code I'm not calling new as an argument, I did it here to shorten code.

I've tested the functions and they work, I just can't get them to work using thread. Here is their signatures.

```
    void serverRun();
    void clientRun();
    void clientRun(string ip);
```

My errors are:

1. Error    C2661   'std::thread::thread': no overloaded function takes 2 arguments
2. abc no instance of constructor "std::thread::thread" matches the argument list

Does anyone have any insight as to what might be happening in this situation?

Comment: Perhaps a not-so-silly question, you included `<thread>`, right ? We don't have much to work with here.

Comment: That looks like a Visual C++ error code -- what version are you using?

Comment: Also, you have an ambiguity problem.  Try `void (ee::Network::*threadProc)() = &ee::Network::clientRun; thread clientThread(threadProc, new ee::Network);`

Comment: Craig, #include<thread> is included.
2. Visual C++ 2015
ben, about to try your suggestion

Comment: @MattStone I can see how that solved your problem (props to Ben), but that error messaging is just plain odd imho for the ambiguity of `clientRun` in your thread creation context.

Comment: My compiler similarly gives `no instance of constructor std::thread::thread matches the argument list` but it goes on to list the argument types as `(<unknown-type>, ee:Network *)` which suggests the ambiguity problem.

Comment: For explanation of why Ben's fix works and some other solution techniques, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984788/c-member-function-overloading-with-ampersand

Comment: Thanks, I accidentally deleted my comment where I said: "ben's solution fixed my problem but I don't understand why it is an ambiguity problem". Thank you for the responses guys. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Ben's suggestion fixed my problem, but I'm not sure why.

The problem is with the first argument `&ee::Network::clientRun`. clientRun has 2 overloads, but at the point of template deduction (to deduce the types of the arguments to `std::thread::thread<>`) the compiler is not yet in a position to distinguish which of the overloads is more valid.

Ben's solution worked because the cast prior to the call has done the compilers' work for it - by specifying the type of `Network::clientRun` to be `void (ee::Network*)(void)` rather than the equally valid `void (ee::Network*)(string)`.

Some examples:

```
#include <thread>
#include <string>

struct Network
{
  void clientRun();
  void clientRun(std::string);
};

int main()
{
  // not ok...
//  std::thread clientThread(&Network::clientRun, new Network);

  // ok - tells the compiler which overload
  auto member_function = static_cast<void (Network::*)()>(&Network::clientRun);
  std::thread clientThreadA(member_function, new Network);

  // also ok
  using call_type = void (Network::*)();
  std::thread clientThreadB(call_type(&Network::clientRun), new Network);
}
```