# Implicitly convert a lamba to a function ptr to create a class

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, implicit-conversion

```
struct myclass
{
    myclass(void(*)()) {}
};

void test1(void(*)()) {}
void test2(myclass) { }
void cb() {}

int main()
{
    test1(cb);      // works
    test2(cb);      // works
    test1([](){});  // works

    test2([](){});  // does not work, why? there's no "explicit" keyword next to myclass.

}
```

Why this doesn't work?

The following obviously works but I don't want to use it.

```
     test2(myclass([]{}));
```

Notes: I do not want to accept a `std::function<void()>>` and I don't want to create a `template<T> myclass(T f) {}` either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only have one user defined conversion - and lambda to function pointer counts as user defined. Instead use some [sorcery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18889028/2069064) to do the function pointer conversion explicitly:

```
test2(+[](){});
```

Note also that the parens in a nullary lambda are optional, so this also works:

```
test2(+[]{});
```

Comment: Yeah I already knew about the parens. Dunno why I had them there. I had no idea about the + trick tho. Thank you very much for that!

Comment: OMG!  That's horrible.  I can imagine using it, but there is going to be a 10 line comment beforehand explaining what's going on!

Comment: @Martin Why would you need a 10 line comment? You see it once, look it up, and you know what it means.

Comment: Last time I checked, this doesn't work on MSVC (or maybe just 32-bit MSVC?) - but maybe they'll fix it one day...

Comment: 10 line comment:  I'd like the explanation inline, also, I'd need the explanation again the *next* time I looked at the code.

Comment: @Martin Barry knows it by heart, he won't understand why you need the 10 lines comment above it.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have *one* user-defined conversion in a conversion sequence. Try:

```
test2(static_cast<void(*)()>([](){}));
```

Or:

```
test2(static_cast<myclass>([](){}));
```

Comment: Upvoted for the user defined conversion answer. Simply accepted Barry's one since it was a bit more complete (it had the + "sorcery" in it), which is sick since I had absolutely no idea about it.