# Obtaining function pointer to lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, c++14

I want to be able to obtain a function pointer to a lambda in C++.

I can do:

```
int (*c)(int) = [](int i) { return i; };
```

And, of course, the following works - even if it's not creating a function pointer.

```
auto a = [](int i) { return i; };
```

But the following:

```
auto *b = [](int i) { return i; };
```

Gives this error in GCC:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:13:37: error: unable to deduce 'auto*' from '<lambda closure object>main()::<lambda(int)>{}'
     auto *b = [](int i) { return i; };
                                      ^
main.cpp:13:37: note:   mismatched types 'auto*' and 'main()::<lambda(int)>'
```

It seems arbitrary that a lambda can be converted to a function pointer without issue, but the compiler cannot infer the function type and create a pointer to it using `auto *`. Especially when it can implicitly convert a `unique, lambda type` to a function pointer:

```
int (*g)(int) = a;
```

I've create a little test bed at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2cbd62c8179dc61b that contains the above examples. This behavior is the same under C++11 and C++14.

Comment: Rules for `auto` deduction are very similar to the template deduction. Here you have deduction and conversion: you can only have one.

Comment: I want to change the question title to "Why does auto * not deduce a function pointer type from a lambda?" in order to make this a concrete question. That seems to be what was puzzling you. But would you prefer something more like "How do I get a function pointer from a lambda without writing the type?"

Comment: That first title sounds good.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This fails:

```
auto *b = [](int i) { return i; };
```

because the lambda is not a pointer. `auto` does not allow for conversions. Even though the lambda *is* convertible to something that is a pointer, that's not going to be done for you - you have to do it yourself. Whether with a cast:

```
auto *c = static_cast<int(*)(int)>([](int i){return i;});
```

Or with [some sorcery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18889028/2069064):

```
auto *d = +[](int i) { return i; };
```

Comment: What does this do? Never seen this kind of `+` syntax before.

Comment: @Jaa-c Added a link.

Comment: Thanks - now I'll have to use it at least once. Reviewer's gonna hate me.

Comment: @Jaa-c just don't `auto *d = ++[](int i){ return i; };` -- a unary plus too many!

Comment: To steal someone else's line from I-don't-know where: this is awesome, yet totally messed up.

Comment: plus 1 for +, I forgot about that.

Comment: @Yakk: I am pleasantly surprised that both `++[] ...` and `+++[]` fail to compile, I guess the `+` thing is less evil than I thought at first glance

Comment: @Chris Maybe because those make a prefix increment operator instead of a unary plus operator? ;)

Comment: Note that `+` fails on at least some MSVC. Because their lambdas have four conversion operators to function pointers :/

Answer (score 8):

> Especially when it can implicitly convert a unique, lambda type to a function pointer:

But it cannot convert it to "a function pointer". It can only convert it to a pointer to a *specific* function signature. This will fail:

```
int (*h)(float) = a;
```

Why does that fail? Because there is no valid implicit conversion from `a` to `h` here.

The conversion for lambdas is not compiler magic. The standard simply says that the lambda closure type, for non-capturing, non-generic lambdas, has an implicit conversion operator for function pointers matching the signature of its `operator()` overload. The rules for initializing `int (*g)(int)` from `a` permit using implicit conversions, and thus the compiler will invoke that operator.

`auto` doesn't permit using implicit conversion operators; it takes the type as-is (removing references, of course). `auto*` doesn't do implicit conversions either. So why would it invoke an implicit conversion for a lambda closure and not for a user-defined type?

Answer (score 5):

The lambda code doesn't work for the same reason this doesn't work:

```
struct foo {
  operator int*() const {
    static int x;
    return &x;
  }
};

int* pint = foo{};
auto* pint2 = foo{}; // does not compile
```

or even:

```
template<class T>
void test(T*) {};
test(foo{});
```

The lambda has an operator that implicitly converts it to a (particular) function pointer, just like `foo`.

`auto` does not do conversion.  Ever.  Auto behaves like a `class T` parameter to a template function where its type is deduced.

As the type on the right hand side is not a pointer, it cannot be used to initialize an `auto*` variable.

Lambdas are not function pointers.  Lambdas are not `std::function`s.  They are auto-written function objects (objects with an `operator()`).

Examine this:

```
void (*ptr)(int) = [](auto x){std::cout << x;};
ptr(7);
```

it compiles and works in gcc (not certain if it is an extension, now that I think about it).  However, what would `auto* ptr = [](auto x){std::cout << x;}` supposed to do?

However, unary `+` is an operator that works on pointers (and does nearly nothing to them), but not in `foo` or a lambda.

So

```
auto* pauto=+foo{};
```

And

```
auto* pfun=+[](int x){};
```

Both work, magically.

Comment: "not certain if it is an extension" I'd expect that to work. You can take a specific function pointer to a function template (e.g. `template <class T> void foo(T) { } void(*p)(int) = foo;`

Comment: @Barry Sure I expect that to work.  But `auto` lambdas are relatively new, and clang rejects it.  Me, I'd even want implicit cast to any function that is convertion-compatible, so even `void(*f)(double) = [](int x){std::cout << x;};` would compile (like it does with `std::function<void(double) f = [](int x){std::cout << x;};`)