# obtain function pointer of bound/inferred capturing lambda with static local variable

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14, generic-lambda

Is it possible to obtain a C style function pointer of a capturing lambda using static local variables?

I am trying to bind the first the argument of the derived function to the `original` parameter

```
template <typename F>
class entry_hook
{
public:
  entry_hook(void* original, F&& hook)
  {
    static auto bound = [&](auto&&... args)
    {
      return hook(original, std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };

    auto* function_ptr = +[](auto&&... args) // -> decltype(bound(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...))
    {
      return bound(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);
    };
  }
};
```

---

Using:

```
const auto hook = entry_hook(nullptr, [](void* original)
{
  // ...
});
```

Fails to compile - unable to convert closure to function pointer

Removing the parameter pack from the wrapping lambda (by changing the following lines):

- `auto* function_ptr = +[](auto&&... args)` to `auto* function_ptr = +[]()`
- `return bound(std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...);` to `return bound();`

Succesfully compiles and runs, although I would have assumed that by using a parameter pack that can be inferred at compile time on a lambda, wouldn't result in that lambda becoming a closure as such (being unconvertable to a function pointer as it requires a context)

---

I'm ideally trying to achieve:

```
const auto hook = entry_hook(nullptr, [](auto original, int param1, double param2)
{
  // ...
});
```

Where `original` is of type `void(*)(int, double)` and `entry_hook` can expose a function pointer to the passed in lambda

---

Reference:

This answer converts a capturing lambda into a function pointer [C++ lambda with captures as a function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852101/c-lambda-with-captures-as-a-function-pointer/48368508#48368508)

This answer converts a lambda into a function pointer [Obtaining function pointer to lambda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709874/obtaining-function-pointer-to-lambda/37710167#37710167)

Comment: Which pointer to function type do you expect from `[](auto&&... args)`?

Answer (score 1):

No: it's impossible.

Because the lambda that you trying to convert to a function pointer

```
[](auto && ... args) { /* something */ }
```

is a generic (and variadic; but the point is that is a generic one) lambda.

So is almost as a (variadic) template function (more exactly: as a struct with a variadic template `operator()` in it) as

```
template <typename ... As>
SomeRetType func (As && ... as)
 { /* do something */ }
```

and you can't have a pointer from `func()`

```
auto fp = &func;  // same problem
```

because `func()` isn't an object but a set of objects.

Comment: is this not achieved in the first answer I referenced?

Comment: @AdamW - Do you mean inside `lambda_traits`? Isn't the same thing. In that class, the `Args...` (and also `R`) types are template types of the `struct`; so, inside the struct, the `Args...` types are defined, not template types. If you transform the `auto && ... args` values in `Args && ... args` where `Args...` are template arguments of the class/struct (or of the method), yes, inside the class/struct (or method) you can do something similar. But not when the template types are free types for the function/lambda.