# Template argument deduction/substitution failed with lambda as function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, template-argument-deduction

I'm wondering why in the following code the compiler is unable to use lambda as the argument for function foo() (template argument deduction/substitution failed), while a simple function works:

```
template<class ...Args>
void foo(int (*)(Args...))
{
}

int bar(int)
{
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    //foo([](int) { return 0; }); // error
    foo(bar);
    return 0;
}
```

The intel compiler (version  18.0.3 )

```
template.cxx(12): error: no instance of function template "foo" matches the argument list
            argument types are: (lambda [](int)->int)
      foo([](int) { return 0; }); // error
      ^
template.cxx(2): note: this candidate was rejected because at least one template argument could not be deduced
  void foo(int (*)(Args...))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing a lambda into a function template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235053/passing-a-lambda-into-a-function-template)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions) doesn't consider implicit conversion.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

You can convert the lambda to function pointer explicitly, e.g. you can use `static_cast`,

```
foo(static_cast<int(*)(int)>([](int) { return 0; }));
```

or [`operator+`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18889028/3309790),

```
foo(+[](int) { return 0; });
```

Comment: Is the `+` trick still considered to be a hack or does it start to be an idiom? I'm not asking if it's well defined, I know it is; just does it adds to the #wtf/line of the code base?

Comment: @YSC I don't know, [it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18889028/3309790)'s quite opinion-based. I like it personally because it looks quite natural to me.

Comment: Why not just `+` instead of that cast?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Its intent might be not clear enough; so you agree to consider it as an idiom as YSC said?

Comment: I guess; but non-surprising magic is less wtf than surprising magic.  There is a narrow level of expertise where "you cannot pass that lambda to a template function expecting a function pointer" surprises yet "oh operator+" dorsn't remove it; outside of that window, the code does what you'd expect and does nothing surprising.  If `+` failed to do the "obvious" thing I'd say it is a harmful wtf.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I got what you mean, and agreed.