# Why does this compile when passing a lambda in direct initialization and assignment but not with copy initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, initialization, variable-assignment

Why doesn't assignment operator allow for a lambda expression when done in the same line the object is declared?

It seems to be working in MSVC though.

Test the code:
https://godbolt.org/g/n2Tih1

```
class Func
{
    typedef void(*func_type)();
    func_type m_f;
public:
    Func() {}
    Func(func_type f) : m_f(f) {}
    Func operator=(func_type f) {
        m_f = f;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // doesn't compile in GCC and clang, it does in MSVC
    Func f1 = []() {

    };

    // compiles!
    Func f2;
    f2 = []() {

    };

    // compiles!
    Func f3([]() {

    });
}
```

Comment: Try `Func f4 = +[](){};` :-)

Comment: @Jarod42 That's amazing! Why is it? o.0

Comment: It is similar to `static_cast<void(*)()>([]() {})` from François Andrieux's answer.

Comment: Oh, I see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889028/a-positive-lambda-what-sorcery-is-this

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`Func f1 = []() {};` is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), which requires two user-defined implicit conversion to construct `f1`, the 1st one is from the lambda to the function pointer, the 2nd one is from the function pointer to `Func`. Only one user-defined implicit conversion is allowed in one [conversion sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Order_of_the_conversions) so it fails.

(emphasis mine)

> If T is a class type, and the cv-unqualified version of the type of other is not T or derived from T, or if T is non-class type, but the type of other is a class type, **user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the type of other to T (or to a type derived from T if T is a class type and a conversion function is available) are examined** and the best one is selected through overload resolution.

and

> Implicit conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:
>
> 1) zero or one standard conversion sequence;
>   2) zero or one user-defined conversion;
>   3) zero or one standard conversion sequence.

For `f2 = []() {};` the appropriate assignment operator is tried to be called, `Func` has one and it expects the function pointer as the argument; only one implicit conversion from the lambda to function pointer is required and then it works well.

`Func f3([]() {});` is [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), the appropriate constructor is tried to be called, `Func` has one and it expects the function pointer as the argument. Then it's the same as `f2`.

You may get the point from the difference between copy initialization and direct initialization.

> In addition, the implicit conversion in copy-initialization must produce T directly from the initializer, while, e.g. direct-initialization expects an implicit conversion from the initializer to an argument of T's constructor.

Answer (score 8):

Your first case involves two implicit conversions, lambda to `void(*)()` then `void(*)()` to `Func`. You can have at most 1 implicit conversion.

If you can eliminate one of the implicit conversions it should work fine. Here are some potential solutions you can try :

```
// Explicit cast to a function pointer
Func f1 = static_cast<void(*)()>([]() {});

// func_ptr is already a function pointer
//  eliminating one of the implcit conversions
void (*func_ptr)() = [](){};
Func f2 = func_ptr;

// The conversion from `void(*)()` is no longer implicit
Func f3{ [](){} };
```

Comment: I would suggest making `func_type` be public in `Func`, then you can do things like `Func f1 = static_cast<Func::func_type>([](){});` and `Func::func_type func_ptr = [](){};`