# Member function template deduction guide or other method to let the compiler know how to call function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, c++17

```
struct setup_entry 
{
    template< typename T >
    void Disable( bool(*p)(T*) ) { ... }
}
```

Calling Disable:

```
setup_entry X;

Case 1: X.Disable( [](int*)->bool{...} );        //FAIL to deduce T
Case 2: X.Disable<int>( [](int*)->bool{...} );   //OK   to deduce T
```

I would like to use case 1. (Easier for the user)

Any ideas?

---

The simplified final solution for the record was to do this:

```
template< typename T >
void Disable( T&& Callback )
{ 
   auto p = +Callback;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but I would recommend against using function pointers as arguments. Either use templates (as all of the standard library does) or use `std::function`. That way you can use *any* callable object (like for example lambdas *with* captures). By the way, unless you need `T` inside your function, using a template for the function object itself would also solve your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that because implicit conversion (from lambda to function pointer) won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions); `T` can't be deduced.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for overload resolution, which happens later.

If you want to stick to auto type deduction, you can convert the lambda to function pointer explicitly, e.g.

```
X.Disable(+[](int*)->bool{...} ); 
//        ^
```

Or

```
X.Disable(static_cast<bool(*)(int*)>([](int*)->bool{...}));
```

Comment: Ha, the first version is as awesome as concise! Do you mind elaborating a bit on the unary `+`?

Comment: @songyuanyao Interesting use of unary `+`!

Comment: @lubgr &  L. F.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889028/a-positive-lambda-what-sorcery-is-this).

Answer (score 1):

First you should know that the type of `[](int*) -> bool {...}` is **not** just `bool(int*)` or `bool(*)(int*)`; it is a unique closure type convertible to `bool(*)(int*)`.

And this type is not deducible in this context.

A solution: explicitly do the conversion.

```
X.Disable( static_cast<bool(*)(int*)>([](int*) -> bool {...}) );
```

Better solution: as [**@Some programmer dude**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440558) says, use a template or use `std::function`. For example:

```
template <typename F>
void Disable(F f)
{
    static_assert(std::is_invocable_r_v<bool, F, int*>, "your message here"); // if you want to ensure that the function is actually valid
    // ...
}
```

Or:

```
void Disable(std::function<bool(int*)> f) { ... }
```