# Function wont accept Lambda but will accept function pointer

Tags: c++, lambda, functional-programming

I am trying to implement a JavaScript map function in C++ but cannot get it to accept a lambda. It works when I use a function pointer but not with a lambda. I understand that a lambda and a function pointer are different; I just don't understand why the foreach function is fine but the map function is not.

Any help you will be very appreciated.

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct List {
    void* buffer;

    ...

    void each(void(func)(T))
    {
        for (u32 index = 0; index < size; index += 1)
        {
            func(((T*)buffer)[index]);
        }
    }

    template <typename OutType>
    List<OutType> map(OutType(func)(T))
    {
        List<OutType> list;
        for (u32 index = 0; index < size; index += 1)
        {
            list.push(func(((T*)buffer)[index]));
        }
        return list;
    }
};
```

Usage Code:

```cpp
i64 addTwo(i32 n)
{
    return (i64)(n + 2);
}

int main()
{
    List<i32> list;
    list.push(4);
    list.push(2);

    // works
    list.each([](i32 num) {
        std::cout << num << std::endl;
    });

    // works
    auto list1 = list.map(addTwo);

    // does not work
    auto list2 = list.map([](i32 n) -> i32 {
        return n + 3;
    });
}
```

Error Output:

```sh
.../main.cpp:53:23: error: no matching member function for call to 'map'
    auto list2 = list.map([](i32 n) -> i32 {
                 ~~~~~^~~
.../list.hpp:86:19: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'OutType (*)(int)' against
      '(lambda at /home/caleb/opengl-starter/source/main.cpp:53:27)'
    List<OutType> map(OutType(func)(T))
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: A lambda is a callable type, yes, but it's callable because it has a function call operator defined.

Comment: The code as-is doesn't compile for many other reasons than what's listed here. Please create an actual [mcve]

Comment: But they are not the same. The first returns int64. The second int32.

Comment: @AndyG Thanks, I may update it to be more easily reproducible. I was just thinking that it would be easily answered by somebody who knows more about lambdas given only my error message.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis I've tried it with the same type as well. that shouldn't be the source of the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function should simply accept a simple type:

```
template <typename F, typename OutType = std::invoke_result_t<F, T const&>>
auto map(F function) -> List<OutType>
{
    List<OutType> list;
    for (u32 index = 0; index < size; index += 1)
    {
        list.push(function(((T*)buffer)[index]));
    }
    return list;
}
```

That way, `F` can be a lambda, a function pointer or any other callable type that can recieve `T`.

If `F` would resolve into any other type that is not callable with a `T`, it would be a substitution error.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/Rh40Cc)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I put in my code and it runs fine.

Answer (score 5):

In this case you can coerce your lambda into a function pointer:

```
auto list2 = list.map(+[](i32 n) -> i32 {
    return n + 3;
});
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/faTMwahcnGGK2Sab)

This only works because the lambda doesn't capture anything. In the general case, your template should distinguish between function pointers and callable things (things with an `operator()` defined).

[here's a thorough explanation for why prepending `+` to the lambda works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18889028/27678)