# Function template accept and return different lambdas

Tags: c++, c++20

I have the function `GetThing` as follows:

```cpp
auto GetThing(size_t index, auto&& l1)
{
    return l1;
}
auto GetThing(size_t index, auto&& l1, auto&&... rest)
{
    if (index == 0)
        return l1;
    return GetThing(index - 1, rest...);
}
```

I want it to be able to work with different lambdas too **while being able to handle other types (meaning non-lambdas, non functions, like `int`, and ...)** , such as

```cpp
std::cout << GetThing(1, 2, 3, 4);   //works, return 3
std::cout << GetThing(1, [] {return 0; }, 
    [] {return 1; }, [] {return 2; }, 
    [] {return 3; } )();             //nope
```

But the problem here being the lambdas are different type, therefore the recursive function will deduced to incompatible return type, so I seems to have to use `std::function` like this, but it's ugly.

```cpp
std::cout << GetThing(1, std::function{ [] {return 0; } }, std::function{ [] {return 1; } }, std::function{ [] {return 2; } }, std::function{ [] {return 3; } })();//works
```

Any possible way to get around this, for example if there is an overloaded `operator()` then it automatically enforce the type to be `std::function`?

EDIT: I am aware of capture-less lambdas can be converted to a function pointer, but how to deduce it that way without `std::decay` in the template? Because I still want to to be handle other types as references

EDIT2: I receive a few answers utilizing `std::variant`, and am thinking of that, besides lambda, the parameter types shall be the same, eg. `std::variant<int, int, int>`. **It maybe possible to add overload to `GetThing`, such that when`std::variant` is holding the same types, it return the thing of that type, otherwise (which is the case of receiving lambdas), returns a `std::function`**

Comment: what is `GetLambda` ? typo? Can you post a [mre]?

Comment: @idclev463035818 Sorry it's a typo, I corrected it

Comment: Are the lambdas not capturing anything? Then you might use function pointer instead of `std::function`.

Comment: Your lambdas *are* always capture-less? Then you can do `GetThing(1, +[]{return 0;}, ...)` (note `+`), which is not as ugly as `std::function`.

Comment: @szppeter *I still want to to be handle other types...* Do you mean lambdas taking different parameter types, or returning different type?

Comment: Btw, your function could be replaced with `std::array{a, b, c}[i]`. Even if you want to keep it a function, I suggest getting rid of the recursion.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, I am aware of that. It's a simplified example of my functions that needs to process some conditions based on some parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may store your functions in an array of variants. This comes with some overhead of course. But this enables to have functions also using captured vars.

This enable to pick a function from such function collection and execute it with given parms as follows:

```
template < typename ARR_T >
struct Collect
{
    template < typename ... T > 
    Collect( T&&...args  ): arr{std::forward<T>(args)...}{}
    ARR_T arr;
    using VARIANT_T = ARR_T::value_type;
    VARIANT_T& operator[]( size_t index) { return arr[index]; }
};

template < typename ... T > 
Collect( T&& ... args ) -> Collect< std::array< std::variant<T... >, sizeof...(T) >>; 

template < typename C, typename ... PARMS >
auto GetThing( size_t index, C&& c, PARMS&&... parms ) 
{
    return std::visit( [ &parms...]( auto&& func)
                      {
                          return func(std::forward<PARMS>(parms)...);
                      }, c[index]);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << GetThing( 2, Collect(  []( int, double) {return 0; }, []( int, double) {return 1; }, []( int, double) {return 2; }, []( int, double) {return 3; }), 1,5.6)<< std::endl;

    int y = 8;
    double d = 9.99;

    std::cout << GetThing( 0, Collect(  [y,d]( int, double) {return d*y; }, []( int, double) {return 1.; }, []( int, double) {return 2.; }, []( int, double) {return 3.; }), 1,5.6)<< std::endl;
}
```

In this case `GetThing` also take the function parameters for calling the lambda, because the call is using `std::visit`. If you "only" want to pick the function, you will get the `std::variant` if you like and can call the function your self.

```
    auto func = Collect(  []( int i, double d) {return d+i; }, []( int i, double d) {return d*i; }, []( int i, double d) {return d-i; } )[2];
    std::cout << std::visit( []( auto&& f) { return f( 9, 7.77 ); }, func ) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Upvoted, very interesting solution. But still can't handle other normal non-lambda/non-function types.

Comment: @szppeter What kind of "handling" do you want to achieve. If the "thing" is not executable, what you want to do with it? The collect class collects "all", so there is no problem. But my GetThing is calling/executing that object what I thought was the idea. What you want to do with non function non lambda types?

Comment: Such as returning n-th int in the parameter list which doesn't involve a function call, that why the function is ``GetThing`` not ``GetLambda`` or any specific. I just want it to return the n-th parameter (beside the ``index``)

Comment: Put it more clearly, I just want a ``GetThing`` function, that can also be used to get a lambda (which may be converted to ``std::function`` or function pointer or anything that works), if it's ever possible

Comment: @szppeter That is already done. The Collect class exactly deliver "any" type you put in, encapsulated into a variant. I can't see your problem, because I see it already solved. Can you add some pseudo code to your question with 1) Store data to collection, 2) Pick some element, 3 ) Do something with the found element. Especially the last point is fully undefined. The collect class already collect all data, pick one element and deliver it back. So what is missing?

Comment: OK I edited my question. Your answers expects the parameter (``c`` in this case) to be ``Collection`` which will fail for simple case like ``GetThing(1, 2, 3, 4);``

Comment: @szppeter Take Collect(1,2,3,4)[2] and you get std::variant<...> with int and value 3.

Comment: This fails if you pass in non-rvalues to `Collect`, as that results in a variant of references, which is illegal.  It also creates N variants in an array, some of which get copies of arguments, which seems inefficient; it uses max(k+sizeof(Ts)...) times sizeof...(Ts) memory in automatic storage, and I doubt most optimizers can avoid that.

Comment: [My improvement](https://godbolt.org/z/nvET1r), which unifies the interface of ``GetThing()`` regarding to my ``EDIT2``

Answer (score 3):

You can return a `std::variant` that contains all input types:

```
template <typename... Args>
std::variant<std::decay_t<Args>...>
GetThing(std::size_t index, Args&&... args)
{ 
  return [index, t=std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...)] 
    <std::size_t... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>) { 
    return std::array{ +[](const std::tuple<Args&&...>& t) { 
      return std::variant<std::decay_t<Args>...>{ 
        std::in_place_index<Is>, std::get<Is>(t)}; 
      } ... 
    }[index](t); 
  }(std::index_sequence_for<Args...>{}); 
}
```

Then you need `std::visit` to visit your returned value:

```
for (std::size_t index = 0; index < 4; index++)
  std::visit(
    [](auto&& f) { std::cout << f() << " "; }, 
    GetThing(index, []{return 0;}, []{return 1;}, []{return 2;}, []{return 3;})
  );
```

Comment: That only works if the index is known at compile time. That is the easy side :-)

Comment: If the index is known at compile-time, you might as well use `std::get` and a tuple.

Comment: Upvoted, I think it's more like a simplified version of Klaus' answer

Comment: This can be cleaned up further; in fact, the recursion can be eliminated.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Recursion of which function?

Comment: @康桓瑋 `GetThing` as written above is recursive, and so is `Get`?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont You mean using `std::index_sequence` to eliminate recursion of both functions?

Comment: @康桓瑋 Sure, that is one way.  I'm just leery of O(N) recursion in my template programming, because I find it makes compile times and memory usage explode even with modest N.  In your case, you are generating O(N^2) total symbol length and O(N^2) code over all of the bodies.  The bodies can be optimized, but that takes time and memory at compile time.  And template compilers are not, in my experience, very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

For captureless lambdas you can use function pointers

```
#include <utility> // std::forward

auto GetThing(size_t index, auto&& l1)
{
    return  std::forward<decltype(l1)>(l1);
}

auto GetThing(size_t index, auto&& l1, auto&&... rest)
{
    if (index == 0)
        return std::forward<decltype(l1)>(l1);
    return GetThing(index - 1, std::forward<decltype(rest)>(rest)...);
}

std::cout << GetThing(1,
+[] {return 0; }, +[] {return 1; }, 
+[] {return 2; }, +[] {return 3; } 
)();// works now
```

will work: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9d3frb)

Also note that, you need to add `+` for converting the lambda to function pointer. Read more:
[A positive lambda: '+[]{}' - What sorcery is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889028/a-positive-lambda-what-sorcery-is-this)

---

Also, in case of lambda with capture you need to use `std::function`. The above one will not be enough/will not work!

Comment: You're not using `std::forward` correctly. (The parameters should be forwarding references, and possibly the return type too.)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Sorry, I forgot. I have corrected it. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: You might also want to mention that it's `+` that makes it work. Adding `std::forward` is just a general improvement.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes added... Thanks

Comment: As a minor improvement, you could do the decay to function pointer inside `GetThing`, and then the call site is the same as OP's. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/janfhx).

Answer (score 2):

As solved by @康桓瑋 a variant is what you want when you have a sum type.

Here is what I think is a cleaner solution.

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
using enumeration = std::variant<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>...>;
```

An `enumeration` is a variant of compile time values.

They are a runtime store of a compile time value which can then be used.

```
template<class T>
struct enum_from_seq;
template<class T>
using enum_from_seq_t = typename enum_from_seq<T>::type;
template<std::size_t...Is>
struct enum_from_seq<std::index_sequence<Is...>>{ using type=enumeration<Is...>; };

template<std::size_t N>
using variant_index_t = enum_from_seq_t<std::make_index_sequence<N>>;
```

A `variant_index_t` is an `enumeration` of 0 to N-1.  It can be used to interact with variants.

```
template<std::size_t N, std::size_t...Is>
variant_index_t<N> make_variant_index_helper( std::size_t I, std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
  constexpr variant_index_t<N> retvals[] = {
    variant_index_t<N>{ std::integral_constant<std::size_t, Is>{} }...
  };
  return retvals[I];
}

template<std::size_t N>
variant_index_t<N> make_variant_index( std::size_t I ) {
  return make_variant_index_helper<N>( I, std::make_index_sequence<N>{} );
}
//TODO: handle valueless_by_exception:
template<class...Ts>
variant_index_t<sizeof...(Ts)> get_index( std::variant<Ts...>const& v ) {
  return make_variant_index<sizeof...(Ts)>( v.index() );
}
```

now we can make an `enumeration` for a variant from a size and a run-time element.

This is annoying machinery, but at least it is generic.

```
template<class...Ts>
std::variant< std::decay_t<Ts>... > pick( std::size_t I, Ts&&...ts ) {
  using return_type = std::variant< std::decay_t<Ts>... >;

  std::tuple< std::remove_reference_t<Ts>*... > retvals = {std::addressof(ts)...};

  auto index = make_variant_index<sizeof...(Ts)>(I);
        
  return std::visit( [&](auto I)->return_type {
    //TODO: perfect forward here.  If constexpr on the Ith Ts maybe?
    return return_type(std::in_place_index<I>, *std::get<I>(retvals));
  }, index );
}
```

see, no recursion.

Test code:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    auto x = pick( i, 3.14, 2, "hello", "goodbye", -3.14 );
    std::visit( [](auto&& x) {
        std::cout << x << "\n";
    }, x );
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2af8086f1659b08b).

Output:

```
3.14
2
hello
goodbye
-3.14
```