# How to bypass C++ inability to match function types in templates with lambdas

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, functional-programming, template-argument-deduction

If you have the following template for filtering list:

```cpp
template <typename T>
inline std::list<T> list_filter(std::list<T> const& a, bool (f)(T)) {
    std::list<T> output;
    std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(output), f);
    return output;
}
```

Then try to call it with the lambda inside like:

```cpp
std::list<int> lst = {1,2,3,4,5};
auto filtered = list_filter(lst, [](int el) -> bool { return (el % 2 == 0); });
```

It will produce the error with `no matching function for call to list_filter(..., std::__cxx11::list<int>)::<lambda(int)>)'`.

Is there any way to bypass that restriction without extracting the lambda into the separate function? Why C++ doesn't allow this obvious pattern?

Comment: Why do you need to specify the signature for your parameter? Just use a separate template parameter for the callable.

Comment: @super for clarity. To avoid the misuse.

Comment: When the callable is passed to `copy_if` it needs to have the right signature, and if not will produce a compile time error. You don't really gain anything in that regard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implicit conversion (from lambda with no capture-list to function pointer) won't be considered in [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Implicit_conversions), which fails to deduce template argument `T` on the 2nd function argument.

> Type deduction does not consider implicit conversions (other than type adjustments listed above): that's the job for [overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution), which happens later.

You can convert lambda to function pointer explicitly by `static_cast`, or `operator+`. e.g.

```
auto filtered = list_filter(lst, +[](int el) -> bool { return (el % 2 == 0); });
```

Or use [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) (since C++20) to exclude the 2nd function argument from deduction. e.g.

```
template <typename T>
inline std::list<T> list_filter(std::list<T> const& a, bool (f)(std::type_identity_t<T>)) {
    ...
}
```

BTW you can make your own `type_identity` easily if your compiler doesn't support C++20.

Comment: That is interesting engineering: `std::type_identity_t`.

Comment: @Const See [non-deduced context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts) for more.

Comment: @AntonKochkov Yes, caputring lambdas can't convert to function pointer. You can change the function parameter from function pointer to `std::function`, (same deduction issue as function pointer, solution above is required too, i.e. use `std::function<bool (std::type_identity_t<T>)>`), or as @someprogrammerdude suggested pass the lambda directly.

Comment: @songyuanyao Could you please give some information about this line: +[](int el) -> bool { return (el % 2 == 0); }

Comment: @FarhadSarvari See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18889028/3309790) for more. `operator+` causes non-capture lambda converting to function pointer.

Comment: @Const If you're interested, I recently wrote [a brief blog post](https://dfrib.github.io/non-deduced-contexts/) on particularly the use of type identity mapping for controlling template argument deduction by removing arguments by placing them in non-deduced contexts.

Answer (score 4):

Lambdas with captures are not compatible with pointers to functions (which is what the argument `f` is).

I recommend that you take a hint from the standard library itself when it comes to callable objects: Use template arguments for the whole callable object:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
inline std::list<T> list_filter(std::list<T> const& a, F f) {
    std::list<T> output;
    std::copy_if(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(output), f);
    return output;
}
```