# No matching function call for lambda function parameter to template function

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates, c++20

Trying to pass a lambda function to a template factory function which is templated on the function arguments of the passed function leads gcc-10.2.0 to report `no matching function for call to ‘test(main()::<lambda(int, double)>)’`.

It does seem to work when I add a `+` in front of the lambda function forcing the conversion to a function pointer, but I don't see why that would be necessary. Why does the conversion not happen automatically? Is there any way to make this work?

I have also tried `std::function<void(TArgs...)> test_func` as argument in the declaration of `make_test`, however that gives me the same `no matching function for call` error.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename... TArgs>
struct test_type {
  test_type(void(TArgs...)) {};
};

template <typename... TArgs>
test_type<TArgs...> make_test(void test_func(TArgs...)) {
  return test_type<TArgs...>{test_func};
}

int main() {
  auto test_object = make_test([](int a, double b) { std::cout << a << b << "\n"; });

  return 0;
}
```

**Edit**

I was wondering if there maybe is some way to make it work with type traits. Something like the following. Although I know of no way to get the argument list from the template parameter.

```cpp
template <typename F>
test_type<get_arg_list<F>> make_test(std::function<F>&& f) {
  return test_type<get_arg_list<F>>{std::forward(f)};
}
```

Comment: Is this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18889029/27678

Comment: @AndyG With or without `std::function`, I think OP is asking how to deduce the parameter types from the lambda.

Comment: @RichardCritten because `auto test_object = test_type<int, double>{[](int a, double b) { std::cout << a << b << "\n"; }}` works as expected. At least it does when I specify the constructor to take `std::function<void(TArgs...)>`, but the same cannot be said for the factory function for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to support a variety of callables being passed to your factory (e.g., a stateful lambda or a function pointer), your `test_type` constructor should accept some kind of type-erased function type like `std::function<void(int, double)>`:

```
template<class... TArgs>
struct test_type {
  test_type(std::function<void(TArgs...)>) {};
};
```

Afterwards it's just a matter of writing the boilerplate to handle the following callables being passed to `make_test`

- a regular function pointer
- a lambda (struct with a `operator()(...) const`)
- a mutable lambda or a user defined callable without a `const` `operator()` function

Here is one approach using type traits:

Start with a base class that we'll specialize for each scenario:

```
template<class T, class = void>
struct infer_test_type;
```

(This is a common setup for the voider pattern. We can do this with concepts and constraints, but I'm feeling too lazy to look up the syntax, maybe later)

**Regular function pointer specialization**

```
template<class Ret, class... Args>
struct infer_test_type<Ret(*)(Args...)>
{
    using type = test_type<Args...>;
};
```

Now we can write a templated alias for simplicity:

```
template<class T>
using infer_test_type_t = typename infer_test_type<T>::type;
```

And we can verify that it works like so:

```
void foo(int, double){}
// ... 
static_assert(std::is_same_v<infer_test_type_t<decltype(&foo)>, test_type<int, double>>);
```

We can use the type trait for our `make_test` function like so:

```
template<class T>
auto make_test(T&& callable) -> infer_test_type_t<T>
{
    return infer_test_type_t<T>{std::forward<T>(callable)};
}
```

Now it's just a matter of covering our other two scenarios.

**Callable objects**

- these will have operator() (either `const` or not)

I'll start with a top level trait to detect the presence of `operator()` and feed the type of `operator()` into another trait.

The top level trait:

```
// if T is a callable object
template<class T>
struct infer_test_type<T, std::void_t<decltype(&T::operator())>>
{
    using type = typename infer_test_type<decltype(&T::operator())>::type;
};
```

You see that internally it's calling back into another `infer_test_type` specialization that I haven't shown yet; one that is specialized for `operator()`. I'll show the two specializations now:

```
// if operator() is a const member function
template<class T, class Ret, class... Args>
struct infer_test_type<Ret(T::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using type = test_type<Args...>;
};

// if operator() is non-const member function
template<class T, class Ret, class... Args>
struct infer_test_type<Ret(T::*)(Args...)>
{
    using type = test_type<Args...>;
};
```

(We could probably combine these two if we wanted to be a little bit smarter and lop off any `const` at the high level before calling down, but I think this is more clear)

And now we should be able to infer an appropriate `test_type` for **non-generic** callables (no generic lambdas or templated `operator()` functions):

a test with a non-const `operator()`:

```
struct my_callable
{
    void operator()(int, double) // non-const
    {
    }
};

// ...
static_assert(std::is_same_v<infer_test_type_t<my_callable>, test_type<int, double>>);
```

And a test with your lambda:

```
auto lambda = [](int a, double b) { std::cout << a << b << "\n"; };
static_assert(std::is_same_v<infer_test_type_t<decltype(lambda)>, test_type<int, double>>);
```

**Putting it all together**

For your simple (non-capturing, non-generic lambda) example it's quite straightforward:

```
make_test([](int a, double b) { std::cout << a << b << "\n"; });
```

#### [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1dczM6fjo)

Comment: Deduction guide can also be added: `template<class T>
test_type(T&&) -> infer_test_type_t<T>;`.

Comment: @Jarod42: Unfortunately the *template name* in the simple template id to the right of `->` in a deduction guide must match the *template name* of the class per [temp.deduct.guide], and I don't see a good workaround here on account of needing to infer variadic arguments.

Comment: Thanks! That is a big mess for something seemingly so simple... You mention concepts and constraints, would that make this any nicer?

Comment: @wich, unfortunately not much. We'd have to build a few things first. Reusable things, but if you aren't doing a lot of metaprogramming, then it probably wouldn't be worth it