# C++20 converting a function template to generic lambda

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20

I have a function template parametrized on a member function, that accepts an object and calls different functions based on whether the return value of that member function on the object satisfies some requirement.

Example:

```cpp
template<auto member> void callerFunc(S* ps)
{
    if constexpr (requires { { (ps->*member)()->f1() } -> std::same_as<int>; })
        useF1((ps->*member)());
    else
        useF2(ps);
}
```

This template is only used in one place, so I'd like to convert it to a lambda and put it inside the function that uses it.  However, the function arguments are not dependent on the template parameter and I do not know how to express it in terms of a lambda (or whether it is even possible).

The full example is provided below and is available on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/EbsTMT8MK).

The actual code is more complex, and uses classes that are generated from protobuf files (with nested messages and `oneof` fields) that I do not control, and macros that generate code in the `switch` cases.

**Edit:**
To clarify: in the code below, setting the `caller` inside the `switch` and calling it outside it is important, since in the actual code the `switch` is in a `try` block and the call is in the corresponding `catch`.

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <iostream>

struct S1 {
    int f1() { return 1; }
    int f2() { return 2; }
};

struct S2 {
    // doesn't provide f1(), use f2() instead
    int f2() { return 2; }
};

struct S {
    S1* getS1() { return &s1; }
    S2* getS2() { return &s2; }

    S1 s1;
    S2 s2;
};

template <typename T> void useF1(T* t) { std::cout << t->f1() << "\n"; }
template <typename T> void useF2(T* t) { std::cout << t->getS2()->f2() << "\n"; }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// How can I move this template inside Thing::foo below?
template<auto member> void callerFunc(S* ps)
{
    if constexpr (requires { { (ps->*member)()->f1() } -> std::same_as<int>; })
        useF1((ps->*member)());
    else
        useF2(ps);
}

struct Thing {
    S s;
    void foo(char c) {
        auto caller = &callerFunc<&S::getS2>; // has to be available outside the switch
        switch (c) {
            case 'a': caller = &callerFunc<&S::getS1>; break;
            case 'b': caller = &callerFunc<&S::getS2>; break;
        }
        caller(&s); // has to be outside the switch
    }
};

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main() {
    Thing thing;
    thing.foo('a');
    thing.foo('b');
}
```

Comment: If it's only used in one place, perhaps it doesn't need to be a template?

Comment: It is used multiple times inside one function.  The code for each case of the switch is generated by a macro to make adding new ones a 1-line operation.

Comment: Pass `member` as a normal (non-template) argument.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit, if you can make it work please submit an answer with the code.

Comment: No time to write an answer but here are two versions [1](https://godbolt.org/z/ocEE7sfxh) [2](https://godbolt.org/z/v9rnnKsWE).

Comment: `std::function` is heavy compared to a captureless lambda (which decays to a function pointer) so I specifically avoided it.  You can compare the generated code.

Comment: I know it is not optimal, you choose what you want, nice syntax or performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare a template lambda and use `.operator()` to access its function call operator to explicitly specify the template parameter

```
void foo(char c) {
  auto callerFunc = []<auto member>(S* ps) {
    if constexpr (requires { { (ps->*member)()->f1() } -> std::same_as<int>; })
        useF1((ps->*member)());
      else
        useF2(ps);
    };

  switch (c) {
    case 'a': callerFunc.operator()<&S::getS1>(&s); break;
    case 'b': callerFunc.operator()<&S::getS2>(&s); break;
  }
}
```

If the caller must be called outside the switch case, then you can create a lambda that makes the caller, and perform type erasure by converting the returned lambda into a function pointer so that it can be reassigned according to different case values

```
void foo(char c) {
  auto make_caller = []<auto member> {
    return [](S* ps) {
      if constexpr (requires { { (ps->*member)()->f1() } -> std::same_as<int>; })
        useF1((ps->*member)());
      else
        useF2(ps);
      };
  };
  
  auto caller = +make_caller.operator()<&S::getS2>();
  switch (c) {
    case 'a': caller = +make_caller.operator()<&S::getS1>(); break;
    case 'b': caller = +make_caller.operator()<&S::getS2>(); break;
    }
  caller(&s);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bWoY6qr6s)

Comment: The actual call has to be outside the switch (in the real code, it is in a `catch` clause).  I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: That's interesting.  I was under the impression that a captureless lambda would convert to a function pointer automatically.  Can you please explain why the `+` is needed?

Comment: Fond this explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889028/a-positive-lambda-what-sorcery-is-this Only the first `+` is needed

Comment: What do you know, the code breaks clang-tidy!  https://godbolt.org/z/T7vY6Ydcq

Comment: And Clang 16 too https://godbolt.org/z/cYse4o87b

Comment: @AlexO Looks Looks like a Clang-tidy bug.

Comment: Yea, I reported it.  Clang trunk chokes on it too.  Answer's still good, even though I may not be able to use it until they fix the bug.  Going to accept it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax to call generic lambda with non deducible template parameter with `lambda.operator()<YourTemplateArg>(/*args...*/)`.

One way to have better calling syntax is to use deducible type helper:

- [`std::type_identity`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_identity) for type
- [`std::integral_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) for "value". (or "equivalent" type to have simpler syntax (get rid of the type)).

So, an helper:

```
template <auto x>
using IC = std::integral_constant<decltype(x), x>;
```

so the lambda:

```
callerFunc = []<auto member>(S* ps, IC<member>)
{
    if constexpr (requires { { (ps->*member)()->f1() } -> std::same_as<int>; })
        useF1((ps->*member)());
    else
        useF2(ps);
};
```

and the call:

```
switch (c) {
    case 'a': caller(&s, IC<&S::getS1>{}); break;
    case 'b': caller(&s, IC<&S::getS2>{}); break;
}
```

Comment: The call has to be outside the switch.  I am setting a pointer in a `try` block and calling it in the corresponding `catch` in the real code.

Comment: You might then set a `std::variant<IC<&S::getS1>, IC<&S::getS2>>`, and `std::visit` later...