# Non-capturing lambda won't degrade to function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

Here is a typical C function that takes a classic function pointer as an argument:

```
int DoThingy( const char* stuff, int(*helper)(int))
{
    int result = 0;
    //...call helper...
    return result;
}
```

Below I call the above with a non-capturing lambda that magically "degrades" into a function pointer. At "A" the conversion is implicit. At "B" it's explicit. All good.

```
void UseThingy()
{
    auto lam = [](int)->int {
        return 42;
    };

    int i;
    i = DoThingy( "hello", lam); //"A" works

    int (*ptr)(int) = lam;
    i = DoThingy( "hello", ptr); //"B" works
}
```

But in this new example, the signature of the callback function depends on a template type:

```
template <typename T>
int DoThingy2( const char* stuff, int (*helper)(T))
{
    int result = 0;
    //...call helper...
    return result;
}
```

When I try to use this version as above, line "C" won't even compile. Yet the explicit version at "D" works. What? Why aren't these the same? Notice when I give an explicit template parameter at "E" it works, but certainly the `<int>` can be inferred from the the signature of `lam`, right?

```
void UseThingy2()
{
    auto lam = [](int)->int {
        return 42;
    };
    
    int i;
    
    i = DoThingy2( "hello", lam); //"C" won't compile

    int (*ptr)(int) = lam;
    i = DoThingy2( "hello", ptr); //"D" works

    i = DoThingy2<int>( "hello", lam); //"E" works
}
```

The following also doesn't compile and I wish it would:

```
    i = DoThingy2( "hello", [](int)->int {return 42;}); //"F" won't compile
```

What I should have said earlier is I need the function parameter to default to `0` so that an internal version of `helper` is used when none is provided by the caller.

Note this question is distinctly different from the proposed duplicate. In particular with regards to optional arguments and further it has a better set of answers using C++17 template selection features.

Comment: I don't know the name of the missed match that happens here, but you _can_ do `i = DoThingy2( "hello", +lam);` to make it work. Note the unary plus on the lambda. See [What sorcery is this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18889029/7582247)

Comment: @TedLyngmo I find that trick so weird that I'd prefer not to tell clients about it. The UseThingy stuff would be in client code perhaps from devs with less esoteric expertise. How does it work--pointers can have arithmetic operations and hence forces the conversion?

Comment: For me the simplest fix seems to be just to qualify the type of the lambda, not using `auto`. This of course depends on your application, but if the type is clear/not too complex, this would work well.

Comment: @TedLyngmo oops, didn't notice your link. Yikes, okay the call site can do the "+" magic. Or one could do as "D". But the question remains, why not as "C"? Is there something I can do on the DoThingy side to make the UseThingy side cleaner?

Comment: @pschulz What do you mean by "qualify the type of the lambda"? Lambdas don't have any type name that is usable by programmers, you can't replace `auto` with anything.

Comment: In D you do the conversion manually. No deduction needed.

Comment: Non-capturing lambdas decay to function pointer, so you can write `int (*lam)(int) = ...`. Poor use of words, not 'fully qualify'. (Which is just the same as D)

Comment: @pschulz that works but I find it almost as "unclean" as line D. What I'd also like is for lambda literals to work without declaring `lam` at all.

Comment: Fair enough. These days, I mostly program in C, so I guess I got used to that :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is with template argument deduction.  When that process runs, no conversions happen, the compiler takes the provided object, gets the type of it, and then tries to deduce the template parameters from this type

In this case the function gets `lamba_object_from_main` (made up type name), when it expects a function pointer.  It can't deduce `T` because `lamba_object_from_main` is the only thing it has to work with.

Instead of using a function pointer you can change the function to just take in anything for the second parameter like

```
template <typename Func>
int DoThingy( const char* stuff, Func helper)
{
    int result = 0;
    //...call helper...
    return result;
}
```

and if you want to make sure that `helper` has a specific return type and parameters you can constrain the template like

```
template <typename Func, std::enable_if_t<is_invocable_r_v<int, Func, int>, bool> = true>
int DoThingy( const char* stuff, Func helper)
{
    int result = 0;
    //...call helper...
    return result;
}
```

---

If you want the function to be optional there is at least a couple options.  One is to change the template to

```
template <typename Func = int(*)(int),
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_r_v<int, Func, int>, bool> = true>
int DoThingy2( const char*, Func helper = [](int i){ return internal_function(i); })
{
    int result = 0;
    helper(result);
    return result;
}
```

which uses a default lambda to call your default internal function

Another option is to have two overloads, one that takes the fucntion and one that does not but calls the one that does with your default function like

```
template <typename Func, std::enable_if_t<is_invocable_r_v<int, Func, int>, bool> = true>
int DoThingy( const char* stuff, Func helper)
{
    int result = 0;
    //...call helper...
    return result;
}

int DoThingy( const char* stuff)
{
    return DoThingy(stuff, internal_function);
}
```

Comment: I should have said that it's a function pointer that defaults to 0. If the caller doesn't provide a helper, an internal version is used. Is your answer commensurate with that? How do you pass in nil for Func?

Comment: @Mustang Have two versions of the function, this main and another in the form of `int DoThingy( const char* stuff) { return DoThingy(stuff, [](int){ return 0; }) }`

Comment: or `[](int i){ return internal_function(i); }` -> `template <typename Func, std::enable_if_t<is_invocable_r_v<int, Func, int>, bool> = true>
int DoThingy( const char* stuff, Func helper = [](int i){ return internal_function(i); })`

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry Nathan, I removed my comment to tinker some more, but, no need :-) I think the template parameter needs a default signature for this though: `template<class Func = int(*)(int)>`. It may be easier to move `std::enable_if_t<...>` to the return type of the function in that case.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Doesn't seem to be needed here: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2614be4e0a38d8c2

Comment: If you remove the supplied `lam`, it'll fail though, so it doesn't use the default lambda but [adding a default signature](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/336b72c5dcafd702) makes it work.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Good call.  I've updated with some options

Comment: In poking around I now see similar ideas using `Func&& helper`. Is that better than `Func helper`?

Comment: @Mustang It really depends.  If `helper` is statefull then passing by reference can be helpful but if not then not really.

Comment: I don't want to add a separate answer for just a loose idea: If one wants to get hold of `T` from `Func`, I guess one could use `DoThingy` as a front for `DoThingyImpl` which is implemented like the original and forward `helper` using unary plus. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/zafWY3EP6)