# C++ type of lambda closure returned from functions

Tags: c++, lambda, closures, c++14

Consider the following example code:

```
int main()
{
    auto id = []()
    {
        auto ret = [](auto u) { return u; };
        return ret;
    };

    //same closure type -- prints '1'
    auto f1 = id();
    auto g1 = id();
    std::cout<<std::is_same<decltype(f1), decltype(g1)>::value<<std::endl;

    //differenct closure type -- prints '0'
    auto f2 = [](auto u) { return u; };
    auto g2 = [](auto u) { return u; };    
    std::cout<<std::is_same<decltype(f2), decltype(g2)>::value<<std::endl;
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6dc7a23c7c8bb677)

Questions:

- Why is the type of the returned closure object identical in the first call of `std:is_same`? (The same result is obtained using a "normal" function template, and also when `add` is defined in the body of `main()`.)
- What is the difference to the second call where -- as I expected from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18756007/2412846) -- the closure types are different?

Comment: Well, you're calling the same specialization of `add`'s `operator()`...

Comment: what is t in "auto f2 = [t{3}](auto u) { return t + u; };"

Comment: @Columbo: I expected the following: when calling `add`'s `operator()`, in the body a new unique closure with a unique type is generated and returned thereafter -- as it also happens in main. What is wrong with this expectation?

Comment: What would happen if the lambda `add` were to be called in a loop with the loop bounds been provided at runtime? How would the compiler be able to generate unique lambda types for each iteration of the loop; I note here that the type used with `add` in all cases is `int` as per the example (see initial post)

Comment: @Niall: I got the example, thanks. And you're right, it's pretty natural: a member funtion with given parameters has a unique return type, not a new one at each call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have extended your (unedited) example a bit to gain some more information:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>
#include<utility>
#include<functional>
#include<array>
#include<tuple>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>


    auto add = [](auto t)
    {
        auto ret = [t](auto u) { return t + u; };
        return ret;
    };

    int main()
    {    
        //same closure type -- prints '1'
        auto f1 = add(3);
        auto g1 = add(4);
        auto h1 = add(1.);
        std::cout<<std::is_same<decltype(f1), decltype(g1)>::value<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<std::is_same<decltype(f1), decltype(h1)>::value<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<typeid(f1).name() <<"\t" << typeid(g1).name()<<"\t" << typeid(h1).name()<<std::endl;

        //differenct closure type -- prints '0'
        auto f2 = [t{3}](auto u) { return t + u; };
        auto g2 = [t{4}](auto u) { return t + u; };    
        std::cout<<std::is_same<decltype(f2), decltype(g2)>::value<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<typeid(f2).name() << "\t" << typeid(g2).name()<<std::endl;

        //using same line multiple times
        std::vector<std::string> types;
        for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
            types.push_back(typeid([t{i}](auto u) { return t + u;     }).name());

        for(auto type:types)
            std::cout<<type<<std::endl;
    }
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1ed231d8fe0e7de)

Example output (from the demo, using g++):

```
1
0
ZNKUlT_E_clIiEEDaS_EUlS_E_  ZNKUlT_E_clIiEEDaS_EUlS_E_  ZNKUlT_E_clIdEEDaS_EUlS_E_
0
Z4mainEUlT_E_   Z4mainEUlT_E0_
Z4mainEUlT_E1_
Z4mainEUlT_E1_
Z4mainEUlT_E1_
```

For me this looks like this:
As stated in the answer you linked, every lambda has its own type.
However the `add()`-function is treated like a template, so theres one specialization for every type (in my example int and float). Since you just call this function twice (for the int part), the same code gets executed twice - and in a strongly typed language like c++ this will of course generate the same type twice. The same happens if called in a loop.
If however a lambda is declared, that just looks the same, the compiler has two (possibly) different expressions to compile - and creates different types. In the example output here there is e.g. "main" included in the typename, probably some reference to the scope where the lambda was declared.